# How get an example value from a z3 model for arrays?

Tags: python, z3, z3py

Thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53239653/how-get-a-a-value-from-a-lambda-expression) I know how to see the model in an easier way. At this point how can I get the expected values for `a` and `another` ?

If possible I'd like the example code using pyz3.

Clarification:

Having the following smt file:

```
(set-option :produce-models true)
(set-logic QF_AUFBV )
(declare-fun a () (Array (_ BitVec 32) (_ BitVec 8) ) )
(declare-fun another () (Array (_ BitVec 32) (_ BitVec 8) ) )
(assert (and  (=  true (=  (_ bv77 32) (concat  (select  a (_ bv3 32) 
) (concat  (select  a (_ bv2 32) ) (concat  (select  a (_ bv1 32) ) 
(select  a (_ bv0 32) ) ) ) ) ) ) (=  true (=  (_ bv12 32) (concat  
(select  another (_ bv3 32) ) (concat  (select  another (_ bv2 32) ) 
(concat  (select  another (_ bv1 32) ) (select  another (_ bv0 32) ) ) 
) ) ) ) ) )
```

I would like to have the value for `a` and `another` that are `77` and `12`

What is the best way?

At the moment my approach is:

```
import z3
import binascii

z3.set_param('model_compress', False)
s = z3.Solver()
s.from_file("first.smt")

s.check()

m = s.model()

print(m)


a = m[m.decls()[0]]

print(a)

b = bytearray(a.num_entries())

for x in range(a.num_entries()):
    index = a.entry(x).as_list()[0]
    value = a.entry(x).as_list()[1]

    print(index, value)
    b[a.num_entries()-index.as_long()-1] = value.as_long()

expected = int(binascii.hexlify(b),16)

print(expected)
```

The output is `77` as expected  :)

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "expected"?

Comment: I suspect you're trying to get the value and turn it into a Python object perhaps? That you can further program with? If that's the case, please post what you have tried and where you got stuck. It's usually not easy to extract array-objects out, but perhaps you don't need them to start with. (You can usually get away with individual elements in the array; but of course this depends very much on the problem you're trying to solve.)

Comment: Hi Levent, I have updated the question. I hope this clarifies my doubts. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

As shown in the original question, the model values for arrays are functions that map indices to values. So, an example value for `a` is `[3 -> 1, else -> 1]`, which is the function that maps index `3` to value `1` and all other indices to value `1`.

Comment: Hi Christoph, I have updated the question. I hope this could help

Answer (score 1):

The sort of usage you have here is extremely brittle. The line:

```
a = m[m.decls()[0]]
```

assumes the model will have the `a` value in the very first slot. It might work for this particular SMT file; but there's no guarantee that it'll always hold.

Your code can be simplified. But I think that's missing the point that this isn't the proper way to use z3. I'd recommend either sticking to SMTLib only or coding in z3py directly. Mixing those two interfaces is just going to add to confusion for no obvious benefit, and as I mentioned, is going to be extremely brittle.

Since you already seem to have something else generating SMTLib; why not just stick to that format? You can use SMTLib's `eval` command to extract arbitrary values from your model. Or, recode everythin in z3py, and use those facilities directly. Also, it is not clear why you're modeling `a` and `another` as arrays to start with: Seems like you're only interested in the `[0]`'th element of those arrays? If that's the case, simply use a 32-bit vector instead of an array.